# How to set up Scala X-Ray plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-xray

I want to use [the Scala X-Ray plugin](https://github.com/harrah/browse).

I compiled the plugin and dropped the jar file - `sxr-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` - in `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins` and wrote Scalatron's `plugin.sbt` (as `project/plugin.sbt`) to configure the plugin as follows:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scala-tools.sxr" % "sxr" % "0.3.0-SNAPSHOT" cross CrossVersion.full)

scalacOptions <+= scalaSource in Compile map { "-P:sxr:base-directory:" + _.getAbsolutePath }
```

Then, I tried to `sbt dist` the project that failed at compilation:

> sbt dist
>   But compilation was failed:
>   .../scalatron-master/project/plugins.sbt:10: error: not found: value CrossVersion
>   addCompilerPlugin("org.scala-tools.sxr" % "sxr" % "0.3.0-SNAPSHOT" cross CrossVersion.full)
>                                                                           ^
>   [error] Type error in expression

Can anyone help me with the plugin's configuration?

Comment: @Charles Changed it to `scala-xray`, which is actually the project name - http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/1509

Comment: Your question says 0.3.0 in one place and 0.3.1 in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the documentation on [the sxr project's page](https://github.com/harrah/browse/blob/master/README.md) and in [Compiler Plugin Support](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Compiler-Plugins.html).

First, the compiler plugin's in the Typesafe Releases repository so you need to add a proper resolver.

Second, the compiler plugin's changed the package that's now `org.scala-sbt.sxr`.

That said, the `build.sbt` of your project should be as follows:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addCompilerPlugin("org.scala-sbt.sxr" %% "sxr" % "0.3.0")

scalacOptions <+= scalaSource in Compile map { "-P:sxr:base-directory:" + _.getAbsolutePath }
```

p.s. [I submitted a pull request to update README.md](https://github.com/harrah/browse/pull/20) in the browse's github repository.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're suppose to put

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scala-tools.sxr" % "sxr" % "0.3.0-SNAPSHOT" cross CrossVersion.full)

scalacOptions <+= scalaSource in Compile map { "-P:sxr:base-directory:" + _.getAbsolutePath }
```

in your `build.sbt`, not `project/plugins.sbt`.